# Implementing Counter in the HTML Template of an Angular2 Component

Tags: html, angular

I' m trying to build a custom calendar. There are still a lot of things to be done but my question on this point is how to implement an counter in my HTML template in an Angular2 Component. More specifically:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let w of weeks">
            <td *ngFor="let d of days">
                <ng-container *ngIf="(day_count <= monthLength && (w > 1 || d >= firstDayOfMonth))">
                    {{ day_count }}
                    // On this point, I want "day_count = day_count + 1"...
                </ng-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Concerning the above variables:

```
 weeks = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 days = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
 monthLength = 28 or 29 or 30 or 31
 firstDayOfMonth = from 0 to 6
```

The variable "day_count" is the variable responsible to show each date of the month. Initially, it has to be 1, then increases by 1, etc, until reaches monthLength. So, how can I make this implementation??

Comment: Can't you just use another `ngFor` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it no template side ,

But I think the solution you need for your code is :

Template Side :

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let w of weeks">
            <td *ngFor="let d of days">
                <ng-container *ngIf="incr(w,d,monthLength,firstDayOfMonth)">
                    {{ incr(w,d,monthLength,firstDayOfMonth) }}
                </ng-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Component Side :

```
weeks = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
days = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
firstDayOfMonth = 0;
monthLength = 31;

incr(w,d,monthLength,firstDayOfMonth)
{
    let day_count = ((w-1)*7)+d;
    if (day_count < (monthLength+firstDayOfMonth)  && day_count >= firstDayOfMonth)
    {
        return day_count - firstDayOfMonth+1;
    }
}
```